# Print out Scala worksheet results in interactive mode in IntelliJ

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, read-eval-print-loop

For some reason, intermediate values aren't being printed out in the REPL console (right hand side of the worksheet)

For instance, this is what I have:

```
object test {
  val obj = new MyObject(1)
  obj.value 
}

class MyObject(x: Int) {
  def value = x
}
```

In the REPL results, I only get the following:

```
defined module test
.
.
.
defined class MyObject
```

However, I don't get any of the intermediate results, such as when I evaluate `x.value`

I would expect something like:

```
> MyObject@14254345
> 1
```

after `x.value`

Any reason why this isn't printing out?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

What ended up working for me in this case (and this might be particular to IntelliJ 14, since I've seen it working the other way in Eclipse) is I added the class inside the object block, like this:

```
object test {
  val obj = new MyObject(1)
  obj.value 

  class MyObject(x: Int) {
   def value = x
  }
}
```

This forced the REPL instance inside the worksheet to auto-evalute the result and print them out on the right hand side.

Comment: Thanks for your help as I was searching for resolution since a day. But being a newbie in Scala, I'm not understanding why this is happening as I believe it works in Eclipse. By the way, this issue is happening in IntelliJ15 too.

Answer (score 11):

To make it work like it does in Eclipse, turn on "eclipse compatibility" mode. This worked for me using IntelliJ IDEA 2016.

`Preferences` > `Language & Frameworks` > `Scala` > `Worksheet`

Then, check the `Use "eclipse compatibility" mode` checkbox.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, I don't have enough reputation to comment so I have to write it here.

If you want to get the result you want, maybe you can try like this.

```
scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

object test {
  val obj = new MyObject(1)
  println(obj.value) 
}

class MyObject(x: Int) {
  def value = x
}


// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

defined object test
defined class MyObject

scala> test.obj
1
res4: MyObject = MyObject@1cd072a9
```

when you paste the code, test and MyObject are not initialized, certainly you can not get any print. 
test.obj will cause test to be initialized so will obj, meantime, obj.value also get evaluated. However, if you don't something about it(like print), it's just a pure expression.

Comment: Thanks. I was looking for something that was already in the worksheet, without having to go to the Scala console.