# Cannot get Scala Worksheet to evaluate inside of an object on Intellij

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

I have been having issues with getting my scala worksheet to evaluate the inside of my objects. The goal is to get something like this: [image]

However I instead get this:
[image]

I have taken a look at both of these questions asked in the past:
[Scala worksheet does not evaluate object in IntelliJ IDEA 2016.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39487425/scala-worksheet-does-not-evaluate-object-in-intellij-idea-2016-2)
[Print out Scala worksheet results in interactive mode in IntelliJ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31566804/print-out-scala-worksheet-results-in-interactive-mode-in-intellij)

I tried copy pasting the code from the accepted solutions as well as checking the `Use "eclipse compatibility" mode` in `preferences` but nothing seems to work.

Comment: An `object` doesn't exist until it is referenced.  In your code `Test` is defined but not referenced. Try adding `Test` on some line after the closing `}`.

Comment: Ok I understand that, and I am only wrapping things in an `object` because my scalafmt formatter complains otherwise. Can you also possibly answer the question of why it bugs me for an object/class when I am working on a worksheet?

Answer (score 0):

change the Scala worksheet settings.

change run type to plain (original it was REPL)

You can get to settings by clicking the settings icon on the Scala worksheet.

[image]